# Sum of multiple text values in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am creating a reading list of books and I want to prioritize them depending on the source that recommended it.

The possible sources include:

- Summary Blog -> 7 points
- London Business School -> 6 points
- Vlerick -> 5 points
- Influential Friends -> 4 points
- Reddit -> 3 points
- LinkedIn -> 3 points
- Blog -> 2 points
- Audible -> 1 point
- Blinkist -> 1 point

So, if the book is only recommended by a summary blog, it should be a priority of 7. If it is recommended by only Vlerick, it should be a priority of 5. However, if it is recommended by Vlerick and a summary blog, it should be a priority of 12.

And the code I have so far is:

> =SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D2,"Summary Blog")), 7, 0), IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D2,"Vlerick")), 5, 0))

It works if it is either a Summary Blog or Vlerick but not when the cell contains both. Then the output it returns is 0 while it should be 12 (see image below).

[image: See this image.]]

Comment: Could you add some sample Source data,, help us to understand data set !!

Comment: Why you use SUM()? Use MIN()...

Comment: @Akina If it is featured by multiple sources I want it to add the scores I give to it. So the expected result is 12.

Comment: Replace ISNUMBER with ISERROR.

Comment: Then it gives 12 for "Vlerick, Summary Blog" but 5 for just "Summary blog" which should give 7. And 7 for just "Vlerick", so it reverses those 2.

Comment: ***Unclear***, please update your original question with some examples of inputs and desired outputs.

Comment: Ok, I've added some more info and the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place the points in a table:

[image]

You can use the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(H$1:H$9,A2))),I$1:I$9)
```

Note that you will have to do one of the following:

1. change "Summary Blog" to "Summary"
2. change "Blog" to "Other Blog"
3. change the points for "Summary Blog" to "5"

For the formula to work properly. This is because the formula detects the "Blog" string inside "Summary Blog" and so both point values get used

Comment: Thank you! It works, I truly appreciate it :)